# How to make Lucene 5.5.0 StandardAnalyzer align with Lucene 2.9.0 StandardAnalyzer?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

The default behavior of StandardAnalyzer is different between Lucene 5.x and 2.x, for example `that's H&M`, using code like below:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
analyzer.tokenStream("text", new StringReader(chunkText));
```

In lucene 2.x, it tokenized to:

> [that, H&M]

While in lucene 5.x, it tokenized to:

> [that's, h, m]

Any way to make lucene 5.x align lucene 2.x results?

Answer (score 1):

Back in Lucene 3, they changed the `StandardAnalyzer` to implement Unicode text segmentation, as specified in [UAX #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/). If you wish to use the old, more simplistic word segmentation algorithm from 2.X, use `ClassicAnalyzer` instead.

Comment: H&M can be tagged correct by ClassicAnalyzer in lucene 5.5, but that's also tagged to `that's`, not `that`. Any idea?